# Update address fields relating to order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to update the data relating to a woocommerce order. I can retrieve the existing data but not update.
Before I start, I've manually created an order by going to the orders page of the Dashboard, clicking the Add Order button then filling in Shipping and Billing address details and adding some products.

Then I create a copy of [woocommerce/checkout/form-pay.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-pay.php) in my theme, to which I add the code:

```
$invoiceid = $order->id;
echo invoiceid;
```

This returns the id number that corresponds with that in the URL, so I know I'm in the right place. I next try drilling into the address details relating to the order. To keep things simple until I have a working process, I'll just update the 'Billing First Name' field. I enter:

```
$billing_first_name = $order->get_billing_first_name();
echo $billing_first_name;
```

Again, it returns the value which I entered in that field when I manually created the order. So far, so good. However, things fall apart when I try to update the value.

After reading [this](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/the-new-crud-classes-in-woocommerce-2-7/) WooCommerce page on CRUD, I tried:

```
$order->set_billing_first_name( 'Foo' );
$order->save;
```

But the value doesn't update. Based on [this](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12634) page, I have also tried:

```
$order->update_meta_data( billing_first_name, 'foo' );
$order->save;
```

This didn't result in the field being updated either.

What is the correct process/syntax for updating this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update order meta with order id. Here is snippet you may change hook as per your requirement. Need to place this code in functions.php.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'digger_checkout_save_user_meta');

function digger_checkout_save_user_meta( $order_id ) {

   //$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  // $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

      update_post_meta( $order_id, '_billing_first_name', 'first name here');
      update_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_last_name','last name' ); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`$order->set_billing_first_name( 'Foo' ); $order->save();`

instead of:

`$order->set_billing_first_name( 'Foo' ); $order->save;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).